# Repair and resubmit message stuck - Service Bus Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, azure, service-bus-explorer

It seems that my Service Bus Explorer application got stuck somehow when trying to perform the "Repair and resubmit message" from the dead-letter queue.

There was a problem with the SMTP server so now i have to resend messages manually, it worked fine for the first 400 messages but then it just randomly stopped working, taking 3 minutes trying to resend a single message and then giving me the error "No message was moved. ~~". It works fine when doing it straight from the Azure Portal but it does not work from the application.

This is the error i am receiving, first i got this error aswell but it at least sent all the messages it could, now it doesnt send any messages.
[ServiceBus Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DqEl.png)

Any suggestions as to why it randomly stopped working manually resending from the dead-letter queue in the Service Bus Explorer application? Are there some cache issues or logs you  can clear? Since it is working in the Azure Portal this seems to be a problem within this program. It is just very hard to debug the cause of the problem..

I tried to change lock duration, increasing the delivery count, updating the version, changing the message id and checking logs but nothing seems to work. I am using "Topics" to send out events.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

*Using the below code we have moved successfully the messages to the Service Bus to the Topic or Queue*

```
ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder conStr;
            QueueClient client;
            try
            {
                conStr = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(QueueAccessKey);
                client = new QueueClient(conStr);

                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.Body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messgae);
                client.SendAsync(msg).Wait();
            }
```

[image]

[image]

*The dead-letter queue stores the messages which are not delivered or not processed.
And the reason for it can be viewed in Azure, as shown in below snippet*

[image]

[image]

for more information on [Service bus message exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions) and [service bus dead letter queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues)